# web2py - Extract value from row object and store in variable

Tags: python, sqlite, web2py

I am writing a simple web2py application and can't seem to figure out how to run comparison checks on variables from db.select statements. Code is posted below:

```
form = FORM('Enter Member ID: ', INPUT(_type='text', _name='name'),
           INPUT(_type='submit', _value='submit'))

if form.accepts(request, session):
    member_id= form.vars.name
    measure_1 = db(db.Detailed_Info.MEMBER_NBR==form.vars.name).select(db.Detailed_Info.MEASURE_1)
    measure_2 = db(db.Detailed_Info.MEMBER_NBR==form.vars.name).select(db.Detailed_Info.MEASURE_2)
    response.flash = 'Form Accepted'


if measure_1=='DBD':
   test = 'IT WORKED'
else: 
   test = 'IT DIDNT WORK'

return dict(form=form, test=test)
```

My question is, I am able to see that the value from the first select statement (that defines variable measure_1) is in fact 'DBD'. But the if statement conditional at the bottom isn't working. I feel it's because the result of the select statement is a "row" object. Is there a way to extract the actual value?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Citing the web2py manual:

DAL Rows is the object returned by a database select. It can be thought of
as a list of Row rows:

```
rows = db(db.mytable.myfield!=None).select()
```

Row contains field values.

```
for row in rows:
    print row.myfield
```

I *suppose* you can also do for example for the first row,

```
result = rows[0].myfield
```

Edit:
Again from the docs, the indexing should work:
Given one row

```
row = rows[0]
```

you can extract its values using multiple equivalent expressions:

```
>>> row.name
Alex
>>> row['name']
Alex
>>> row('person.name')
Alex
```

Comment: Ugh, thanks so much. I read that section of the manual so many times, for some reason it wasn't landing that the measure_1 variable above is the rows, not row.

Comment: Though interestingly enough, the indexing in your second example doesn't work. It states that the index is out of range, not sure why the list would have an index not starting at 0, any ideas?

Comment: You're welcome, that happens, sometimes we don't see the error because we've read through it too much times... I wrote "I suppose" because I haven't used web2py. In docs it says it can "be thought of as a list", which may mean it is not a list but another iterable object, maybe that's why it doesn't work.

Comment: @ArjunArun It looks it works like a list, see my edit. Maybe you are getting no rows. Try `if rows is None:`.